# Pandas read csv converts float to Nan

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to read a csv file via pandas with following data (excerpt from https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.MKTP.CD)

```
"Afghanistan","AFG","GDP (current US$)","NY.GDP.MKTP.CD","537777811.111111"
"Burundi","BDI","GDP (current US$)","NY.GDP.MKTP.CD","195999990"
```

with my command

```
    GDP = pd.read_csv('world_bank.csv')
```

In my Dataframe `"537777811.111111"` is converted to `NaN`
while `"195999990"` is converted correctly.

There seems to be an Issue with float conversion. How can I prevent that?

Comment: That except works fine for me. Can you provide an example that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually tell Pandas to use specific datatype for specific column.

```
import np
...your code...
#Let's say you name your columns:
COL_NAMES=['Country','CountryCode','GDP_Type','WhateverField','GDP']
# you can specify datatype for a single column and let Pandas guess the rest:
COL_TYPES={'GDP':np.float64 }
GDP=pd.read_csv('world_bank.csv',names=COL_NAMES,dtype=COL_TYPES)
```

Similar constructs do the trick for me.

See also: 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html